# How can start service background music using live stream URL in android app

Tags: java, android, service, android-mediaplayer

I have developed android app RADIO stream.

My app working fine on music play so I want to add Radio live stream URL like : http://162.244.80.118:4900/;stream.mp3

So anyone can help me how can add URL and play background music `service` for live radio app.

Here is start `service` code which I use for music play on android background music

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

/**
 * Created by User on 9/22/2017.
 */

public class MyService extends Service {

    private MediaPlayer player;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
        player.setLooping(true);
        player.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        player.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ExoPlayer which is an application level media player built on top of Android's low level media APIs and you can create it to stream from the service.Please refer to this link for the implementation part.
https://github.com/ayalus/ExoPlayer-2-Example/blob/master/ExoPlayer2Example/app/src/main/java/com/ayalus/exoplayer2example/MainActivity.java